# Jmeter MarshalException: error marshalling arguments

Tags: azure, jmeter, distributed-testing

I configured jmeter to run the test distributed using Azure Windows Virtual Machines. All machines are using windows.

The test ran successfully using the GUI mode and I can get the result saved on master
However when I try to run the test from the console **jmeter -n -t plan.jmx -r** the console says:

> Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.MarshalException: error marshalling arguments; nested exception is:
>   java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.jmeter.JMeter$ListenToTest

I' ve configured all the virtual machines (server and clients) like:

```
Java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
Jmeter version 2.13
Jmeter Plugins 1.31
```

Any ideas what could be the issue?
Thanks

### EDIT

I Downgrade Java version to 1.7 and now the error says

> Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.MarshalException: error marshalling arguments; nested exception is:
>           java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.jmeter.threads.RemoteThreadsListenerTestElement

Can Jmeter Plugins the cause of the issue?

### EDIT - FIXED

I changed Plugin version from 1.31 to 1.21 and now works!!!.

However I think, and i'm just guessing here, the error happens when I ran the test from GUI and then on the console. Probably GUI leaves a socket open or something like that, not sure.

Anyway this combination works

```
Java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
Jmeter version 2.13
Jmeter Plugins 1.21 (only Standard Version)
```

Comment: Could you show the full stack trace ?

Answer (score 6):

Check the logs in jmeter.log (inside bin folder) file and if you have somewhere an error like this:

```
2018-09-17 14:41:32,097 ERROR o.a.j.e.ConvertListeners: Error replacing class org.apache.jmeter.threads.RemoteThreadsListenerTestElement by wrapper: class org.apache.jmeter.threads.RemoteThreadsListenerWrapper java.rmi.RemoteException: Cannot start. yout-pc-name is a loopback address.
```

Then start the jmeter by giving:

```
./jmeter -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=your_ip_address
```

Answer (score 4):

I was struggling with:

```
NotSerializableException: org.apache.jmeter.threads.RemoteThreadsListenerTestElement
```

The problem in my case was:

```
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
```

This error info did not appear in the standard output, just the log file.